# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "voaacenc"

Tags: gstreamer

i try to execute

```
gst-launch-1.0 -em rtpbin name=rtpbin latency=5 udpsrc port=5102 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)48000,encoding-name=(string)OPUS" ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. ! queue ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! voaacenc ! mux. udpsrc port=5104 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_1 rtpbin. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mux. flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=false location="rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/show/stream live=1"
```

Unfortunately it raise an error: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "voaacenc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try running `gst-inspect voaacenc`?

Try installing  `gst-plugins-bad`, should solve it.

Comment: please accept the answer, in case it solved the issue.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, i'm using CentOS

Comment: Try exporting the environment variable 

export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0:$GST_PLUGIN_PATH